# How to make Snackbar open again?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I created a `Snackbar` component.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Snackbar, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

interface AlertProps {
  message: string;
}

interface AlertState {
  open: boolean;
}

export default class Alert extends Component<AlertProps, AlertState> {
  constructor(props: AlertProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: true
    };
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }
  handleClose(event: React.SyntheticEvent | React.MouseEvent, reason?: string) {
    if (reason !== 'clickaway') {
      this.setState({
        open: false
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Snackbar
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
        open={this.state.open}
        autoHideDuration={6000}
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        message={this.props.message}
        action={
          <IconButton
            key="close"
            color="inherit"
            onClick={this.handleClose}
          >
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
      />
    )
  }
}
```

I then programmatically add it to a render when an error is encountered while submitting a form.

```js
let alert: ReactNode;
if (this.state.error) {
  alert = <Alert message={this.state.error} />;
}
```

Problem is the `Snackbar` only opens the first time an error is encountered. If a user submits the same form twice, the `Snackbar` doesn’t open.

I know it’s because of `this.state.open = false` which is set by the `onClose` method, but how can I "reset" this state before the form is submitted again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is you could change your approach a bit and always have `Alert` rendered, i.e.

```
<Alert message={this.state.error} open={this.state.open} onClose={()=>{this.setState({open:false})}}/>
```

Also move the `open` state variable from `Alert`'s state to its parent. So in `Alert` use the `open` value from props always. Now, whenever `open` is changed in the parent, `Alert` will re render properly.